# Magento 2 Installation - 503 (Service Unavailable) Error

Tags: php, wamp, magento2

Tried installing `Magento 2` using setup wizard. All the checks were correct and installation was completed till `90%`. After that it did not show any progress for many hours.

When I run the `http://localhost/magento_2`, it takes forever to load and prints `503` error

[image: Service Unavailable_img]

As mentioned [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_mod_access_compat.html)
I tried debugging as Apache 2.4 changes the way certain directives related to `.htaccess` work.

**Suggested solution on website**

As a user with `root` privileges, enter the following commands:

```
a2enmod access_compat
service <name> restart
```

How do I debug this issue on my local WAMP server and succesfully install Magento 2 with sample data ?

Comment: What error are you seeing in your apache logs?

Comment: `PHP` Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. but i have already set  `max_execution_time = 18000` in `php.ini` file.

Comment: Check your php.ini memory_limit to make sure it's at least 768M. Make sure Apache server rewrites are enabled. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I had this same symptom and it was solved when I disabled maintenance mode.
Seems like when installation is not completely finished, Magento does not disable maintenance by itself.

This is the command I used: magento maintenance:disable

More on this link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html